# How do a I copy or clone a build configuration in QuickBuild version 5.1?

Tags: quickbuild

How do a I copy or clone a build configuration in QuickBuild version 5.1?

I want to create a copy of a configuration and then edit it slightly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the parent configuration of the configuration you want to clone. Go to page called Children in top navigation bar. Click on one of the icons next to the configuration you want to clone.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to find a button on the configuration I wanted to copy rather than on it's parent.